# Bootstrap alerts: content in a div?

Tags: html

Why is it acceptable for [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/) to put content directly into a <div> tag? [eg](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts).

```
<div class="alert alert-block">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
    Best check yo self, you're not...
</div>
```

What about semantics? Shouldn't the text be enclosed in a paragraph in such a situation?

Comment: Why do you think it would be unacceptable? <div> can enclose most stuff.

Comment: @mgkrebbs, because it has no semantic meaning, and that's a text we show to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is closely related to [this other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/4356/15703). In short, `div` is a generic way to structure documents, while `p` denotes a paragraph. Since you're speaking about semantics, I'm not really sure that **all** text must be divided in paragraphs. In that particular case (a simple alert) the entirety of the text contained in the `div` is a single sentence, so the concept of "dividing a single sentence in paragraphs" doesn't even make sense to me.

Otherwise, for longer texts, it totally makes sense to group related sentences in paragraphs, even search engines can "understand" your contents better if you use them correctly. Some newer HTML5 tags (such as `header`, `footer` etc) serve the same purpose: explicitate the semantics of your document for better treatment by automated agents, even though "generic" divs would be enough for human readers to understand (since for us the visual placement of elements on screen is what matters, regardless of the internal code used to represent it).

Answer (score 0):

The alerts aren't permanent and usually close when clicked. So the chance they'll be indexed is low. That said using an `h4` on a page should be ok, since h1's, and h2's are more common and depending on the placement of the alert the h4 is likely showing up lower than the h1 which would be a title at the top of the page.